# Images in foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using foundation to build a fluid responsive layout.

I have images in the form of svgs - I need to put them into my page.

What would be the best way to do this?

Put them in as an image and size the image using a % width or should I put it inside a div that uses:

```
<div class="small-3 meidum-4 columns">
```

So it sizes with the layout.

What's best practice?

Comment: in bootstrap, there's a class 'img-responsive'

Comment: @Filype ok, I'll just go ahead and recode my entire project to bootstrap then :/

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be to set your own css, because using the grid columns to limit your image width doesn't feel like a nice solution.

If you're setting your own css, maybe you want to copy the bs styles

```
// Keep images from scaling beyond the width of their parents.
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; // Part 1: Set a maximum relative to the parent
  height: auto; // Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching
}
```

I believe there's some documentation on handling images in foundation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html

Comment: Thanks but im not referring to interchange as its not required with svgs. Im more looking how to place images in a layout, should they be in columns, or should I place it in and use css to stlye give it a width of eg. 10%?